# How can I access into view of RemoteView?

Tags: java, android

The idea is to get `SurfaceHolder` of `SurfaceView` of a widget or notification.
I have wid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/root" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/sfv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In service I can get just a RemoveView

```
RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.wid);//sfv1
        int ll = layout.getLayoutId();
```

How can I get a access into `sfv1 (SurfaceView)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't. Here's a list of supported layout classes and widgets that `RemoteViews` supports, and `SurfaceView` is not seen among them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: Is where the other methods to get access to surfaceview of widget?